# Scroll content of a grid using jquery

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have a grid (table) and I want to scroll the content using the drag movement.

What I have so far is:

```
var gesturesX = 0;
    var gesturesY = 0;

    var startPosition = 0;
    var velocity = 0;
    var isMouseDown = false;

    var timer;

    function GetVelocity() {
        velocity = startPosition - gesturesY;
    }

    $('.k-grid-content').mousemove(function (e) {
        gesturesX = parseInt(e.pageX, 10);
        gesturesY = parseInt(e.pageY, 10);
        $("#mouse").html(gesturesY);
        if (isMouseDown) {
            $('.k-grid-content').scrollTop(startPosition - gesturesY);
            return false;
        }
    });

    $('.k-grid-content').mousedown(function () {
        startPosition = gesturesY;
        isMouseDown = true;
        timer = window.setTimeout(GetVelocity, 50);
    });

    $('.k-grid-content').mouseup(function () {
        isMouseDown = false;
        return false;
    });
```

With this I'm able to scroll dragging. But my problem is, for instance, if I scroll until the middle of the grid, stop, and after return to scroll beginning at the same point I left, it restart and it begin at the top of table... Is it understandable what I mean?

I would like to continue at the same point... But I'm not seeing how I should do that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your `startPosition` is always calculated from the top of the element; you need to take into account the scroll state at start.

In your `mousedown` event:

```
startPosition = gesturesY + $(this).scrollTop();
```